# JUnit-like test framework for C++ in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, unit-testing, eclipse-cdt

I'm looking for a test framework for C++ in Eclipse CDT. Ideally it should have similar functionalities to those offered by JUnit.

I tried CUTE. It is good but I cannot seem to create unit tests within the project I'm currently working on. Neither can I create a separate unit test project to test my current project, because my current project is a C++ hello world application, but CUTE only allows testing project for a C++ library.

Any idea of other test frameworks I may count on, and is there any tutorial available? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you describe with CUTE is that you need to find a way to split up your application so you move the functionality you want to test to a library. Every test framework will put this requirement on your project structure.

Try GoogleTest or Boost.Test.

GoogleTest does not have a plugin for Eclipse.

see this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=40

Cppunit is abandonware in the sense that it is not actively being maintained anymore.

Comment: Does it make cppunit invaluable though? :)

Comment: Does GoogleTest have Eclipse plugin?

Comment: @Topi Ojala: historically it has great value and a lot of projects are still using it. If you start from scratch I'd recommend to pick one of the more recent once, since they made a big step forward. CppUnit was great, but it doesn't seem to evolve.

Comment: The README file that comes with GTest's installation package is hard to follow. Do you happen to know any useful tutorials that might help me to setup GTest? Thanks.

Comment: Where in the README did you get stuck?

Comment: g++ -I${GTEST_DIR}/include path/to/your_test.cc libgtest.a -o your_test

Comment: I got " undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: Give g++ the option -lpthread or -pthread to link with the POSIX thread library.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4794/discussion-between-eddy-pronk-and-shuo)

Answer (score 9):

I use Google Test Framework and Google Mock Framework with Eclipse CDT C/C++ Tests Runner plugin. This plugin also works with qt tests and boost tests. Look and feel like junit in java eclipse :)

Google test framework is very well described here:
http://code.google.com/p/googletest/

Eclipse CDT C/C++ Tests Runner plugin:
https://github.com/xgsa/cdt-tests-runner/wiki/Tutorial

You can use it by creating new project for test or directly in current project by creating separate build and run action for test runner. I have 2 folders in my project, Source and Tests, Tests folder is exclude from normal build, so I can run test and build application using one project.

Comment: C++ test runner is now part of eclipse CDT - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741400/eclipse-cdt-plugin-for-running-tests-and-browsing-report

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cppunit?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/

I don't use eclipse, but they seem to have a page explaining how  to integrate both:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=CppUnitWithEclipse

There are many tutorials if you search on Google.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I found this posting in my quest for a simple CppUnit integration with Eclipse CDT... So for everyone like me who is seeking a simple CppUnit integration with Eclipse CDT:

I have created an Eclipse plugin to support vanilla CppUnit XML Test Reports with the official Eclipse CDT C/C++ Unit Testing Support plugin.

I have made it available at:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsecppunit/

Answer (score 1):

Well there is https://github.com/xgsa/cdt-tests-runner/wiki/Tutorial for eclipse with google test

Comment: try to give answer from our community

Answer (score 1):

CppUTest is a C/C++ based unit xUnit test framework for unit testing: http://cpputest.github.io/

It is still actively maintained, and there's [CppUTest Eclipse Plugin](https://github.com/cpputest/CppUTestEclipsePlugin) "made to make unit testing easier to work with CppUTest & Eclipse", and **acts like JUnit plugin**.

You can also have a look at [CppUTest Test Runner for Eclipse Juno or above](https://github.com/tcmak/CppUTestEclipseJunoTestRunner)